# Get/set pixel from Graphics object GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, pinvoke, gdi+

I'm trying to find an alternative solution to getting/setting pixels at certain position in a Graphics object.
Right now I'm using GDI functions:

```
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetPixel(System.IntPtr hdc,  int nXPos,  int nYPos);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int X, int Y, int crColor);
```

I couldn't find any for GDI+. GetPixel/SetPixel seems to be on Bitmap object only.
The alternatives from gdi32.dll work well when the Graphics is backed by the screen but when using Graphics with a bitmap it doesn't work anymore (GetPixel returns black, since this works on another bitmap not the actual one): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311221

Some sample code:

```
private void ChangeImage(Graphics g)
{

        IntPtr gDC = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                gDC = g.GetHdc();


                // get the pixel color
                Color pixel = ColorTranslator.FromWin32(GetPixel(gDC, x, y));


                //change pixel object and persist
                SetPixel(gDC, x, y, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(pixel));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (gDC != IntPtr.Zero)
                    g.ReleaseHdc(gDC);
            }

}
```

Is there any way to parse the the Graphics object per pixel basis?
The Graphics object represents a surface where the user is free to add any objects including hand drawing. On top of this I need to apply filters (like blur or pixelation) on some screen parts so I need to access what has been painted already in the graphics.
I've also tried to find a way to persist the current graphics to a Bitmap and use GetPixel from the bitmap object but I've also couldn't find a way to save Graphics content.

Thx

Comment: Graphics is always temporary.

Comment: Use a bitmap to hold the image, then you can call `GetPixel`

Comment: @L33TS Of course it is temporary in it is always associated with a device context: screen, image, some control. But that doesn't mean we can't manipulate what it has been drawn already.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to read pixels from a Graphics object directly. You would need access to the underlying HDC or Bitmap object to do this.

Comment: That's bad news because the underlying object is sometimes the screen and sometimes a bitmap when I need to save the objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim bmap As New Bitmap(550, 100)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmap)

    ' Dont use the Graphics interface, use the BitMap interface
    DIM col as color = bmap.GetPixel(x,y)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: See the comment.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question; and doesn't even use the same programming language as the question.